# Modify nested state with Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I run into a problem that is litterally blowing my mind. 
I'm developing my web application using React and Redux, my application use a system of notification implemented with Firebase.
Every notification is structured as below:

```html
var notification = {
  from_user:{
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe'
  },
  payload:{
    message:'Lorem ipsum ...'
  }
  seen:false,
  timestamp:1569883567
}
```

After fetched, notification is send to notificationReducer with:

```html
  dispatch({type:'FETCH_NOTIFICATION_OK',payload:notification})
```

And so far everything is ok.

My notificationReducer is structured as below:

```html
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  loading:false,
  notification:{}
}

const notificationReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case 'FETCHING_NOTIFICATION':
      return {...state,loading:true}
    case 'FETCH_NOTIFICATION_OK':
      return {...state,loading:false,notification:action.payload} // I THINK PROBLEM IS HERE
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default notificationReducer;
```

The problem is that, when I pass state props to my presentational component, **notification object is empty**

My presentational component is reported below

```html
import React from 'react';

import {getNotification} from '../actions/actioncreators';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

 class NotificationDetail extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetch_notification('9028aff78d78x7hfk');
    console.log(this.props.notification) // IT PRINTS: {}
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        'TODO'
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return {
    is_loading:state.notificationReducer.loading,
    notification:state.notificationReducer.notification
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return {
    fetch_notification: (id_notification)=>dispatch(getNotification(id_notification))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(NotificationDetail)
```

Any suggestion ?

EDIT: In my reducer I tried to print the new state. I succesfully got this: [image]

But, Anyway In my presentational component I got an empty object

Comment: you're not calling `fetch_notification`

Comment: It's showing the initial state. You're never fetching the notifcation

Comment: I forgot to paste my line of code ' this.props.fetch_notification()' in my post. Anyway action is being succesfully dispatched and notification object is returned from Firebase (populated with fields) . The problem is still in the reducer; it seems I cannot modify notification object in state

Comment: How do you know, that your notification is empty? When you are doing this `console.log(this.props.notification)` in `componentWillMount` there will be obviously empty, because you just called fetch in the previous line. Is it also empty in the render method (the last call of it)?

Comment: I tried to render each of its value inside the render() method of my Component. Like <div> {this.props.notification.from_user.name}</div> and I get always the error : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Comment: I suppose it will be empty in the first render. Try to put in `render` just that logging from `componentWillMount` (i.e. do not render that notification, just print it to console) - console.log(this.props.notification). I think the render will be called at least twice, the first time with empty notification and the second time with updated value. Then you can fix that simply - if notification is empty render nothing and if it is not render what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the dispatch call hasn't fired yet. Try executing the below

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetch_notification();
}

render() {
  console.log(this.props.notification); // It should print an output here if your xhr/ajax/axios call is correct
}
```

Also, using componentWillMount is UNSAFE (according to the ReactJS current documentation). Avoid using this lifecycle in the future.